# Flask returns 404 even though route is clearly defined

Tags: flask

I've got some function using a blueprint:

```
@election_blueprint.route("/getlast/{string:type}")
def get_specific_last(election_type: str):
    some code here
```

And then I register this blueprint before starting an app:

```
app.register_blueprint(election_blueprint, url_prefix="/election")
```

And, after that, Flask says that this method is defined in routes:

```
# FLASK_APP='owo/app.py' flask routes
Endpoint                     Methods  Rule
---------------------------  -------  ----------------------------------------------------------
elections.get_elections      GET      /election/find/{string: type}
elections.get_last           GET      /election/getlast/
elections.get_specific_last  GET      /election/getlast/{string:type} <-- There it is!
```

But when I try to get it from client, I get 404, even though other methods, even declared in this blueprint, appear to work fine. What am I doing wrong?

For example, if I just go to

```
http://localhost/election/getlast/sometype
```

It returns 404, but if I use another method, like

```
http://localhost/election/getlast/
```

It works fine.

Comment: 404 is a **client error**, so take a look at what you're sending in the request (and then post it here so we can see it too).

Comment: @Z4-tier I've added it, but since I'm just opening it in a browser I guess it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I guess the variable name on the route should match the variable name on the function. E.g: `@election_blueprint.route("/getlast/<election_type>")`. Also I believed there's a typo the way it is written on your code using "{" instead of "<".

Comment: @KennyAires It made no effect, so I guess it's not the case here

Comment: @KennyAires Oh, it actually worked! I'm so sorry :D I've missed the part with <> instead of {}. I guess you can add it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Nice! I posted a more elaborated answer just in case. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a typo the way it is written on your code using "{" instead of "<". Also, the variable name on the route should match variable name on the function:

```
@election_blueprint.route("/getlast/<string:election_type>")
def get_specific_last(election_type: str):
    some code here
```

good ref on: https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-routes/
Hope it suits you well :)